# Publisher Mail Merge to PDF and Save as Merged Field

Tags: vba, ms-access, save, pdf-generation, mailmerge

I thank you all in advance for any help you can provide me, I am looking to perform a mail merge from access to Publisher. I have linked everything together and got everything looking the way that I want it to look however...

What I want to do is when I perform the mail merge I would like publisher to save a copy of each individual record from the database as a specific file based on one field of the mail merge.

I will try to clarify...

One of the mail merge fields is ClientAccountNumber I would like the merge to save a copy of the publisher file into c:\mailmerge as a PDF including the year 2014.

So this file(s)for example would look like

C:\mailmerge\123456 - 2014.pdf
C:\mailmerge\123457 - 2014.pdf etc...

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how I would go about it?

Regards

Richard

So I have made some progress with this I have created the following macro I haven't written a loop into it yet but I feel that I am getting closer...

However what is now exported is FileNameTemp - 2011 and not the actual client reference and 2011????

I am determined to crack this your help or thoughts would be massively appreciated!

```
Sub MailMerge() 
 '
 ' Macro1 Macro

Dim TempDocCreate 
Dim FileNameTemp As MailMergeDataField 


Set FileNameTemp = Application.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item("Box 22 Rcp Acct No") 


With ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource 
    Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
    "L:\Operations Database\Projects\1042\PublisherPDF\2011 Merge\" & "FileNameTemp" & " - 2011" & ".pdf" 


End With
```

End Sub

Your help as always is appreciated!

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify this right now, but I think you need something more like this:

Dim FileNameTemp As String

Set FileNameTemp = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Item("Box 22 Rcp Acct No").Value

' don't put "" around FileNameTemp

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
    "L:\Operations Database\Projects\1042\PublisherPDF\2011 Merge\" & FileNameTemp & " - 2011" & ".pdf"

What I cannot tell is how your code is producing one output PDF for each data source record.